# Compile multiple files in C language

Tags: c, compilation

I have two C files and want to compile it in single file. One file is compiled via make command and another file is Mysql database connection file which is compiled by another command.

So basically I want to include this database connection in my main code file.

Mysql connection file compilation command:
-> gcc -o mysql_test $(mysql_config --cflags) mysql_test.c $(mysql_config --libs)

Main code compilation command:
-> make

The make file as below,

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
SRCDIR = ./src/
BINDIR = ./bin/
OBJDIR = ./so/
SAMPLEDIR = ./ejemplo/
SYSOBJDIR = /usr/lib/
SYSINCLUDE = /usr/include/
ASTSOUNDDIR = /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/
ASTAGIBINDIR = /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/

all:    $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.o $(OBJDIR)libagicapiutils.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c -o $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.o $(SRCDIR)libagicapi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c -o $(OBJDIR)libagicapiutils.o $(SRCDIR)libagicapiutils.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.so $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.o $(OBJDIR)libagicapiutils.o

clean:  
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)*
    $(RM) $(BINDIR)*

install: $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.so
    install -m 0744 $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.so $(SYSOBJDIR)libagicapi.so
    install -m 0744 $(SRCDIR)libagicapi.h $(SYSINCLUDE)libagicapi.h

sample: $(OBJDIR)libagicapi.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINDIR)libagicapisample $(SAMPLEDIR)ejemplo.c -lagicapi
    mkdir -p $(ASTSOUNDDIR)/es/libagicapisample/ $(ASTSOUNDDIR)en/libagicapisample/
    @echo "*------------------------------------*"
    @echo "*   Cree la siguiente Extension en   *"
    @echo "*        su Plan de marcado          *"
    @echo "*                                    *"
    @echo "*exten => num,1,AGI(libagicapisample)*"
    @echo "*------------------------------------*"
    if id -u asterisk >/dev/null 2>&1; then\
        install -m 0744 -o asterisk -g asterisk $(BINDIR)libagicapisample $(ASTAGIBINDIR)libagicapisample;\
        install -m 0744 -o asterisk -g asterisk ./sound/es/menu.wav $(ASTSOUNDDIR)es/libagicapisample/menu.wav;\
        install -m 0744 -o asterisk -g asterisk ./sound/en/menu.wav $(ASTSOUNDDIR)en/libagicapisample/menu.wav;\
    else\
        install -m 0744 $(BINDIR)libagicapisample $(ASTAGIBINDIR)libagicapisample;\
        install -m 0744 ./sound/es/menu.wav $(ASTSOUNDDIR)es/libagicapisample/menu.wav;\
        install -m 0744 ./sound/en/menu.wav $(ASTSOUNDDIR)en/libagicapisample/menu.wav;\
    fi\

$(OBJDIR)libagicapi.o: $(SRCDIR)libagicapi.c $(SRCDIR)libagicapiutils.c
$(OBJDIR)libagicapiutils.o: $(SRCDIR)libagicapi.c $(SRCDIR)libagicapiutils.c
$(OBJDIR)libagicapi.so: $(SRCDIR)libagicapi.c $(SRCDIR)libagicapiutils.c
```

So, I want to include Mysql connection command into this main make file, please guide me on this. How I can put mysql compilation command in above make file. Thanks.

Comment: And how is your makefile now??

Comment: Make file link is below: (libagicapisample this is main code and in this i want to add mysql connection)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/agi-c-api/
in this repo make file is there

Comment: No it is not, your question must be self-contained. Please make a simplified example of the Makefile you're using.

Comment: ok I updated makefile content, please check

Comment: The commands under *all:* target are in *wrong place*. They should go under their respective object files.

Comment: libagicapisample is my executable file and it is working, i just want to know how mysql compilation command i can include in this make file

Comment: So, just type it in there, but because `$()` needs to go to shell and not makefile, you should use `$$(...)` or perhaps the makefile syntax `$(shell mysql-config ...)` would work. Your makefile is still **just plain wrong**.